# How to insert wifi scan data into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have scanned wifi data in C# that I have split into required form MAC, SSID and RSSi. When I push a button, the results should be inserted into a SQL Server table that I already created. And if I push the button again, it stops inserting. I have tried several methods and could not get it to work, Will appreciate assist

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WICED_SERIALPORT_TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

           foreach (string port in ports)
           {
               comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
           }
       }

       string t;

       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           t = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
           sErial(t);
       }

       SerialPort sp;

       void sErial(string Port_name)
       {
           sp = new SerialPort(Port_name, 115200, Parity.None,8, 
     StopBits.One);    
           sp.DataReceived += new 
           SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
           sp.Open();
       }

       private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, 

       SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
       {
           SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
           string msg = string.Empty;
           bool canCont = false;

           while (!canCont)
           {
               msg += sp.ReadLine();

               if (msg.Contains("Scan complete "))
               {
                   canCont = true;
               }
           }

           //string w = sp.ReadLine();
           //string w = sp.ReadExisting();

           // string msg = sp.ReadExisting();

           string[] msgArr = msg.Split('\r');

           Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Clear()));

           List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
           List<Networks> Scan = new List<Networks>();

           for (int i = 0; i < msgArr.Length; i++)
           {
               list.Add(msgArr[i].Split(new string[] { "  " }, 
   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
           {
               if (i > 2)
               {
                   if (list[i].Length > 4)
                   {
                        int numOfSplits = 0;
                        List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

                        for (int ii = 0; ii < list[i].Length; ii++)
                        {
                            if (numOfSplits < 6)
                            {
string[] temp1 = list[i][ii].Split(new char[] { ' ' },  
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                numOfSplits += temp1.Length;

                                for (int iii = 0; iii < temp1.Length; iii++)
                                {
                                    tempList.Add(temp1[iii]);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tempList.Add(list[i][ii]);
                            }
                        }

                        Scan.Add(new Networks()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(tempList[0]),
                            NetworkType = tempList[1],
                            MAC = tempList[2],
                            RSSi = Convert.ToInt32(tempList[3]),
                            Rate = Convert.ToDouble(tempList[4]),
                            Channel = Convert.ToInt32(tempList[5]),
                            Security = tempList[6],
                            SSID = tempList[7],
                        });
                    }
               }
          }

          if (msg != String.Empty)
          {
              Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(msg)));
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < Scan.Count; i++)
          {
             Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(Scan[i].MAC)));
             Invoke(new Action(() => listBox2.Items.Add(Scan[i].RSSi)));
             Invoke(new Action(() => listBox3.Items.Add(Scan[i].SSID)));

             msg = string.Empty;
             list.Clear();
          }
      }

    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=    
(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AP_SCAN_DATA.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True");

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data  Source=
(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AP_SCAN_DATA.mdf;   
Integrated Security=True"))
        {
           using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
           {
               command.Connection = connection;            // <== lacking
               command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               command.CommandText = "INSERT into LOCATIONSCAN ((Scan[i].SSID), (Scan[i].MAC),(Scan[i].RSSi)) VALUES (@SSID, @MAC, @RSSi)";

               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSID", listBox1);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAC", listBox2);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RSSi",listBox3);

               try
               {
                   connection.Open();
                   int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
               catch(SqlException)
               {
                   // error here
               }
               finally
               {
                   connection.Close();
               }
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have an empty `CATCH` block that will cause your SqlExceptions to disappear silently. Remove the CATCH and the exception will help you. Secondly, your CommandText looks odd, without knowing your database schema I would guess it should be something like this;

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT into LOCATIONSCAN (SSID, MAC, RSSi) VALUES ('@SSID', '@MAC', '@RSSi')";
```

Next issue is that you have to specify the property of the listbox that holds the value when adding the parameter. For example it might be the SelectedValue property.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSID", listBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Thanyou I will give it a go and post the result

Comment: Thanyou for the response tried what you suggested i got an error at line 187 .....                  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: @Olu There is only one line of SQL so it is not the SQL that errored at line 187. What exactly was the error? What is the code at line 187 that you refer to? What have you tried? You have to make some effort to help yourself, otherwise why would anyone here want to help you?

Comment: Sorry about that i ama novice. I remove the CATCH block and edited the commandText the program then stoped at   connection.Open();
            int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();          the error was ArgumentException was unhandled "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.ListBox to a known managed provider native type."